# How to stop inserting the same data into mysql

Tags: mysql, redis

I have a form, and if the user refresh after he submitted this form when the network speed is slow, he will insert two same datas into mysql, I do something like following to stop this.

1. In client(browser), I create a random number, and use this to stop inserting same datas.
2. In server, I use redis, check in redis, and then insert into mysql.

Do you have any other better ways? Many thanks.

Comment: Use a [`UNIQUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique) key on the table to prevent duplicate insertions.

Comment: I recommend that, have a hidden id field in the form.. that will be unique to each inserted record. Else, have a unique field in the form data that you collect like email, lastname+firstname, or some combination of the fields as unique.. and define that in your mysql table schema.. then mysql doesn't load the data if it is a duplicate. Let me know your correct situation in more detail, if this can't be implemented.

Comment: @Arihant I am doing that in redis, I hashed some keys' value, and store in redis, and check before inserting into mysql in server side, and in client side(browser), I use random number for checking, and I think both of them are very basic, I want a more advanced way.